# How can I make this object mutable

Tags: java, immutability, mutable

I have this simple immutable object:

```
public class Alt {
public LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

public void refresh() {
    Random rand = new Random();

    list.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        list.add(rand.nextInt(32));
    }
}

public void compare(Alt alt) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(alt.list.get(i) + " " + list.get(i));
      }
   }
}
```

However this class is an immutable object, for example when I run:

```
Alt a = new Alt();
a.refresh();
Alt b = a;
b.refresh();

a.compare(b);
```

The values that return are the same, the object b act's like its a shortcut to the object a and is more or less a duplicate. Is there a way to make it so that b is separate? Or am I doing this in completely the wrong way.

Comment: What? There's nothing immutable about that class.

Comment: a and b are same reference.

Comment: By doing `Alt b = a;` you're having `a` and `b` pointing to the exact same object!

Comment: "the object b act's like its a shortcut to the object a" Yep. Actually, it's a reference to the same value as `a`. "and is more or less a duplicate" No, it's just the same object.

Comment: *object b act's like its a shortcut to the object a* - Yup. *and is more or less a duplicate* - Nope. *Is there a way to make it so that b is separate?* - Sure, don't point them to the same object. *Or am I doing this in completely the wrong way.* - Probably, but then you haven't explained what your goal is.

Comment: Since its a reference, is there a way that I can duplicate it? Any way that I can make two separate variables that had the same values at one time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your terminology is wrong. This is not an immutable object. The `refresh()` method modifies the object. In the following code will output two different lines:

```
Alt a = new Alt();
a.refresh();
System.out.println(a.list);
a.refresh();
System.out.println(a.list);
```

Also, because the field `list` is visible from outside the class, it can be modified directly:

```
Alt a = new Alt();
a.refresh();
System.out.println(a.list);
a.list.set(10, 42);
System.out.println(a.list);
```

The behaviour you observe is caused by the fact that `a = b` does not create a new copy of the object. It only makes the *reference* `b` point to the same object as the reference `a`. Since there is only one object, `a.compare(b)` will print the same numbers twice.

To make a copy of the object, you will have to program this yourself. In Java, this is often done by a so-called *copy constructor*:

```
public Alt(Alt original) {
    list = new LinkedList<>(original.list);
}
```

(Note how that copy constructor calls the copy constructor of `LinkedList`, which makes a copy of the list.)

Now you can write:

```
b = new Alt(a);
```

and then `b` will be a reference to a new object which happens to contain the same data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding in your question. First of all, your class is actually mutable. You can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) about the strategy of defining immutable objects.

Secondly, the observed behavior you mentioned is due to the passing reference. You can read more info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).